# Is there a way to list the blobs in a specific directory of an Azure Storage Container, using ACL?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, acl

Is there a way to list the blobs in a specific directory of a container, using ACL and the storage REST API?

Example: I have a container named "cars". In that container I've created 2 directories; "volvo" and "tesla". I have a service principal for the volvo user and a service principal for the tesla user and I've set access permissions to "Read" (ACL) for volvo on the volvo directory and vice versa for tesla.
I've given both service principal execute access on the container, all according to the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control and I'm not using RBAC at all. So far so good.

Now I would like to pass this URL to the volvo user, for that user to list all the files in the volvo directory: https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/cars/volvo?restype=container&comp=list but it doesn't work to add the directory name to the URL (I guess it's because restype=container, but I've tried directory as a parameter and that's not valid). This works: https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/cars?restype=container&comp=list but this will list the tesla directory in the container (although not the blobs in it) and I don't want the volvo user to know that there is a tesla directory in the container.
Anyone knows if it's possible, or is it a limitation in the API?

Comment: Can you try the following URL: `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/cars?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=volvo/`? Other alternative would be to use [`Path - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) REST API.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't stop the user for testing "prefix=t" etc to find out which other directories there are in the container.

Comment: Then I think you would need to use DataLake API (Path - List one). Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't get the GET request on the Data Lake API to work - do you have an example of what the URI should look like?